# Errors with dynamically generated pages in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to error handle my spreadsheet which dynamically generates a custom number of worksheets based on a template that we use regularly in excel using VBA.

I have created an "Overview" page where we can input a range of page names which copies the "Master" page content and then generates the worksheets naming them with the values in the page name range.

[image]

My code does what I want it to do but I get a 1004 runtime error (Application-defined or object-defined error) **AND** an extra page is generated named master (2).

```
Sub copySheets()
Dim MyNames As Range, MyNewSheet As Range

Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("master")
Set MyNames = Range("B7:B31") ' load range into variable

For Each MyNewSheet In MyNames.Cells ' loop through cell range
    masterSheet.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'copy master template sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = MyNewSheet.Value

Next MyNewSheet

MyNames.Worksheet.Select ' move selection to original sheet

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, not sure why it'd make a difference, but try changing `in MyNames.Cells`  to just `MyNames` and see if that helps.  What line does the run-time error occur on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to loop through all `Range("B7:B31")` cells and don't stop if we find empty cell, then we just need to add: `if MyNewSheet.Value <> "" then .... End If`

like this:

```
For Each MyNewSheet In MyNames.Cells ' loop through cell range
 if MyNewSheet.Value <> ""
    masterSheet.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'copy master template sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = MyNewSheet.Value
 End If    
Next MyNewSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `Exit For` statement when the first blank/empty cell is encountered. The error is happening because you're trying to assign a null string to the sheet's `.Name` property.

```
For Each MyNewSheet In MyNames.Cells ' loop through cell range
    If MyNewSheet = vbNullString Then Exit For
    masterSheet.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'copy master template sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = MyNewSheet.Value

Next MyNewSheet
```

Or, use a `Do` loop:

```
Dim r as Long
Dim myNewSheet as String
r = 1
MyNewSheet = MyNames.Cells(r).Value
Do Until MyNewSheet = vbNullString

    masterSheet.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'copy master template sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = MyNewSheet
    r = r + 1
    MyNewSheet = MyNames.Cells(r).Value
Loop r
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MyNames range doesn't seem to mean what you think it means. You seem to think it means the total number of cells within column B that have a page# listed, when actually, it means the whole section of column B up to row 31.  You need to define MyNames based on the number of non-blank cells within that section, and then run the remainder of your function on that limited range.

My assumption is that it tries to create a new sheet with a null value for a sheet name, and errors at that point.

One method of determining how far down column B to go would be to define a new variable as an integer, to hold the row number that last contains data. Something like:

```
dim lastRow as Integer
...
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
...
Set MyNames = Range("B7:B"&lastRow)
...
```